# Image inside of a flexbox keeps breaking flex box when the width of the window gets larger

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am attempting to create a responsive splash page that will be cover most of the page in view(90vh). On top it has a logo and on the bottom a simple paragraph.

I have tried to use flex-shrink and flex-basis but it doesn't seem to work in a way that resizes the top image and doesn't bump the bottom text out size of the actual container.

I am not sure what I am missing here. It feels like the size of the image is somehow overriding the flexbox when the page in view gets wider than tall.

Here is a jfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jtpetqtk/

```css
.splash-container{
 display: flex;
 height: 90vh;
 flex-direction: column;
 text-align: center;
 border: 10px solid goldenrod;
 justify-content: space-around;
}

.logo{
 background: red;
 img{
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
 }
}

.mission{
 background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="splash-container">
  <div class="logo">
   <img src="http://www.ticotimes.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/150118Carrotandstick-800x800.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="mission">
   <h1>Mission Statement</h1>
   <p>Our mission is to create a flexbox that doesn't break. It should be responive and contained in 90vh. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you if this is too easy of a fix but you are writing Scss and the fiddle only shows CSS, so the img selector is never working.

It works if you switch to scss or change the selector to proper css:

`.logo img {
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 80%;
}`

https://jsfiddle.net/jtpetqtk/2/

Comment: Thanks @wesbos I appreciate your time. This seems to still break out the outside of the 90vh container at larger widths and I don't see why it should

Comment: thank you so much! This works when the ad is place in div and the flexbox break, set the height and width as suggested and fixed!